# Spring MVC @PathVariable with url address throwing error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

is there a way to send parameter like "https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6164 "  in @PathVariable as part of the URI path ...in Spring Web MVC

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Details/{Emailaddress}/{URL}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Status Details(@PathVariable("Emailaddress") String Emailaddress,
             @PathVariable("URL") String URL) {
try {
            bankingData.callingmethod(Emailaddress,URL);
            return new Status(1, "Details added !");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            return new Status(0, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

error:The requested resource is not available

Comment: Is the {URL} being used to identify the resource which you are going to work with? If not {URL} should be accepted as a query parameter, not as path variable. Anyways you still can send an http URL as query param or path variable by encoding the the URL portion.

Comment: try to post full method

Comment: @Fahim Farook encoding the the URL portion should it must be done in client side only or can i do it in server side also.?

Comment: @Abdelhak please check modified posted code

Comment: Can you post the url are you using?

Comment: @Abdelhak http://123.343.2.12:8080/services/Details/flora@gmail.com/http://`567.322.2.23/ddfdfdfdf

Comment: try now the updated answer

Comment: I wouldn't recommend adding email-addresses as Path-variable, but as RequestBody parameters. You can encode in JS from front-end and then send it to the controller methods. Check out URL encoding in JS or whichever front-end framework you are currently using.

Comment: Encoding the URL is a task of the client. When the request reaches the rest resource method, it's already in the decoded form and you do not have to programatically decode it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is but you have to encode it properly. Use [`URLEncoder.encode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to do so:

```
String url = 
    "http://server/Details/"+URLEncoder.encode("http://myserver/mypath/to/url/", "UTF-8");
```

This code must be performed on client side when constructing the URL. The encoding must be applied to both pat elements and query parameters.

Comment: can you please explain me, where should i encode or put above code in my context?

Answer (score 1):

Try to write `url` like `{URL:.+}` in your method like this:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/Details/{Emailaddress}/{URL:.+}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Status Details(@PathVariable("Emailaddress") String Emailaddress,
         @PathVariable("URL") String URL) {
```

The requestParameter with dot `.` is truncated.

Comment: http://123.343.2.12:8080/services/Details/flora@gmail.com/http://sasasas its not working after doing as you advised.same error